# How do you configure consumers for RabbitMQ to run on a different machine than RabbitMQ message queue?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm using C# for my project and I've successfully set up the RabbitMQ Message Queue with a windows service that publishes to the queue.  I've also created another windows service for a consumer on the same machine as the RabbitMQ message queue.  Is there a way to have the consumers running on a different machine than the message queue?  Everything works great locally right now, but I envision having separate machines for the producers, message queue, and consumers.  I'm not sure if there's a built-in way to do this or if I need to employ something else to communicate between the message queue and my consumers.  Thanks!

Comment: You pass a connection string somewhere, and that currently has the value "localhost" in it. Change that to the hostname or IP of the host running the queue.

Comment: Perhaps also some network config for firewalls (software or hardware), etc., to allow the port from external sources.

Comment: Maybe a firewall block connection to rabbitMQ serveur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the consumer | publisher there will be a connection string that will most likely point to localhost with a user/pass of guest.  You will first need to setup a new user in RabbitMQ that can access the vhost you need access and then update the connection.